# Date Convertion From String

Tags: c#

I have a string "03/13/13" and when i convert this to `DateTime` it is throwing error as `invalid string format`.

How to convert string "03/13/13" to DateTime "03/13/13" (Same Format)

```
Convert.ToDateTime("03/13/13", new CultureInfo("en-GB"))
```

Comment: Your input string is in MDY format, but your locale is DMY. The correct answer is given below BUT you might want to check as to *why* you are getting an MDY formatted input value in the first place. It could be that you should be using the invariant culture when parsing data from a file, and the local culture when displaying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) with format `"M/d/yy"`

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("03/13/13", "M/d/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Where in format:

> ```
> M - For single digit or double digit month
> d - For single digit or double digit day
> yy- for two digits year.
> ```

You may see: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Later if you want the string representation in the same format you can do:

```
string str = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yy")
```

Comment: Throws a `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` error

Comment: @DGibbs, my bad, missed the year part, it should be `yy` not `yyyy`

Comment: @Habib Yep, compiles fine now. Have a +1

Comment: @SSS, did you check the latest code in the answer, I missed up the year part with `yyyy` it should have been `yy`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Convert.ToDateTime` or `DateTime.Parse` ..

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("5/17/2012");
```

or

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse("5/17/2012");
```

**Example**:

```
 string date = "5/17/2012";
 DateTime dates = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

Comment: Nope, still throws the same error, i strongly suggest you test your code before posting it as an answer.

Comment: Hey i have tested it and it works fine for me..Have u tried the same code which i posted.

Comment: Yes I have, it doesn't compile. Look at this line `DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse("mm/dd/yyyy");` what's wrong with it...? Does `mm/dd/yyyy` look like a date to you?

Comment: Hey "mm/dd/yy" is a format.I just gave it for OP's understanding.Replace that with ur own date and it will work..Didn't u see the last 2 lines of my answer i gave an example..

Comment: Seriously, plug this code into a compiler and tell me you don't get an error. Even with the last two lines only it throws `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`.

Comment: protected void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
      DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("5/17/2012");
      lbl.Text = date.ToString();
    }

Comment: Exact same error as before. `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` I'm done discussing this, you clearly have no idea what you're doing

Comment: I dont know whats happening with you..I have showed my output screen itself then also u are tell my code is wrong..Anyway please remove the downvote because its not fair to give a downvote for correct answer.